# how to modify zone file in AWS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, reverse-dns, domain-registrar

If a domain was purchased from a registrar A but the DNS settings for that registrar point to Amazon, where do I edit the zone file in AWS? Do I have to create a new Hosted Zone or edit a zone file inside the Linux EC2 instance? Where do I find the file?

In the ubuntu machine there is no /etc/named.conf

Any idea where I can add my MX settings that the registrar provided? without impacting existing urls and dns settings and certificates?

Comment: Best to say what's the actual domain name - then we can tell where it is hosted, etc. Domains are public anyway, no need to try to keep the name from us if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS's [Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/route53/index.html), you can create *hosted zones*, which is basically the logical equivalent of a zone file. You can modify it's entries via AWS's web console. Manually editing zones-files with a text-editor is not intended from AWS. No EC2-Instances or other servers need to be involved.

To make these *hosted zones* work for your domain, you must list AWS's DNS-Servers in your domain's NS-Record. When creating a hosted zone, it's NS-Records default to use AWS-DNS-Servers which can be used for this purpose.